Plotly express px.scatter, categorical variables to not overlap
I'm trying to compare the categorical assignments of the same items returned by two databases. I want to plot each database on a categorical axis, then use px.scatter to visualize the intersections between them.
The problem I'm running into is px.scatter doesn't seem to have an option to allow for jittering the datapoints so they are not all on top of each other. I found an option scattermode=group with scattergroup=[0,1], but it doesn't do anything in my case.
I am able to get what I want out of JMP. How can I replicate this in plotly express?
MWE
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Document_Type_x': ['Research Article', 'Research Article', 'Letter to the Editor', 'Letter to the Editor', 'Letter to the Editor'],
     'Document_Type_y': ['Article', 'Article', 'Letter', 'Letter', 'Letter']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

fig = px.scatter(df, x='Document_Type_x', y='Document_Type_y')

fig.update_layout(scattermode='group', scattergap=.9)
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder = 'category ascending')
fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder = 'category ascending')

fig.show()


Using px.scatter, incorrectly stacking all data points

Using JMP, correctly showing how many points at each intersection


I had never used this feature before, so I checked the reference again. In this example, it is possible with a color category, so I intentionally add that category. And again modify the legend, marker color, and hover template caused by the addition of the color category. It is a hacking approach, but I think it will get you what you are after.
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

d = {'Document_Type_x': ['Research Article', 'Research Article', 'Letter to the Editor', 'Letter to the Editor', 'Letter to the Editor'],
     'Document_Type_y': ['Article', 'Article', 'Letter', 'Letter', 'Letter']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['type'] = ['A','B','A','B','C'] #update

fig = px.scatter(df, x='Document_Type_x', y='Document_Type_y', color='type')

fig.update_traces(showlegend=False, marker=dict(color='blue')) #update
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='Document_Type_x: %{x}<br>Document_Type_y: %{y}<extra></extra>') # update

fig.update_layout(scattermode='group', scattergap=0.9)
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder = 'category ascending')
fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder = 'category ascending')

fig.show()



Nice trick ! Though having the additional column hardcoded is not very handy. You can  compute it by counting the occurrences of x/y pair : df['xy_idx'] = df.groupby(['Document_Type_x','Document_Type_y']).cumcount().astype(str) and set color='xy_idx' instead (renamed because more meaningful than 'type').

@EricLavault Your comments are excellent. Your point is right on.

Thanks! Good to know I wasn't missing an obvious flag, but frustrating to know this isn't easier. Maybe a different plot type would be more appropriate, but I couldn't immediately see one.
